# How do we trade and earn profits in future contracts?

Tags: stocks, futures, day-trading, derivatives, cme-group

Suppose there is a future contract with a market price of $100 and its lot size is 50, so can I purchase the lot at $100? And while selling before expiry or in intraday, suppose the price is $150, so will I get the return equivalent of $(150-100)*50?

Comment: Futures contracts do not have strike prices, to start with. Strike Prices are options, not futures.

Comment: Most (maybe all) futures contracts are quoted in a _unit price_. So your futures contract will be for $5,000 total, not $100. And you don't "purchase" a futures contract like you do a stock. You enter into the contract and pay the difference when it settles (or when you sell to close your position).